# How do I use Gateway replyTimeoutExpression

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

In my `application.properties` I have written:

```
example.requestTimeoutExpression = 60000
example.replyTimeoutExpression = 60000
```

But how do I use this when I configure the MessagingGateway?

```
@Component
@MessagingGateway
public interface ExampleGateway {
    @Gateway(
        requestChannel = "exampleInput",
        replyChannel = "exampleOutput",
        requestTimeoutExpression = "???",
        replyTimeoutExpression = "???"
    )
    Object send(Object request);
}
```

None of these work:

- `"example.requestTimeoutExpression"`
- `"#{example.requestTimeoutExpression}"`
- `"${example.requestTimeoutExpression}"`

While the provided solutions seem to help me with my original question.
The timeout has no effect.
I'm clearly misunderstanding something.
This seems to have effect:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow exampleFlow(
    @Value("${example.remoteTimeout}") long remoteTimeout
) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("exampleInput")
        .transform(...)
        .handle(Tcp.outboundGateway(Tcp.nioClient(host, port)
                ...
            )
            .remoteTimeout(remoteTimeout)
        )
        .transform(...)
        .channel("exampleOutput")
        .get();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properties are not currently supported there; please open a new feature issue on GitHub; here is a work around:

```java
@Bean
Long reqTimeout(@Value("${example.requestTimeoutExpression}") Long to) {
    return to;
}

@Bean
Long repTimeout(@Value("${example.replyTimeoutExpression}") Long to) {
    return to;
}
```

```
@Component
@MessagingGateway
interface ExampleGateway {

    @Gateway(
        requestChannel = "nullChannel",
        replyChannel = "exampleOutput",
        requestTimeoutExpression = "@reqTimeout",
        replyTimeoutExpression = "@repTimeout"
    )
    Object send(Object request);

}
```

Comment: I found another workaround: `replyTimeoutExpression = "@environment.getProperty('example.replyTimeoutExpression')"`

Comment: You can also add the timeouts as args to the `send` method, e.g. `send(Object request, long replyTimeout)` then `replyTimeoutExpression="args[1]"`.

Comment: Your solution works. It does seem to set the value. Unfortunately setting requestTimeout and replyTimeout to very low values doesn't seem to trigger a timeout. Which makes me think I misunderstood something.

Comment: The `replyTimeout` clock does not start until the thread returns to the gateway (assuming an async downstream flow). For a synchronous flow, it is meaningless because it immediately is satisfied. The `requestTimeout` only applies if the channel is one that can block (such as a bounded `QueueChannel` that is full; see the javadocs for the properties.